# Should you take a sample when doing EDA?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, data-mining

Suppose i have a large dataset, such that python graphing libraries are unable to handle. Is it a good idea to take a random sample? Specifically if it's a classification task, and where the target is imbalanced. Could anyone point me to a rigorous resource to give this a theoretical explanation. Thanks

EDIT : I'm aware of oversampling or undersampling techniques before creating a machine learning model. Im curious about

Should i take a sample, before plotting the relationship of my variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article which discusses classification with imbalanced data: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218001409007326.

The article mentions that:

> Classification of data with imbalanced class distribution has
>   encountered a significant drawback of the performance attainable by
>   most standard classifier learning algorithms which assume a relatively
>   balanced class distribution and equal misclassification costs.

I can propose three options that I know of:

1. Create a balanced data set if you have plenty of data for each class, undersampling.
2. Synthesize samples for your classes with few samples, oversampling.
3. Make use of stratified sampling.

> Stratified sampling refers to a type of sampling method . With
>   stratified sampling, the researcher divides the population into
>   separate groups, called strata. Then, a probability sample (often a
>   simple random sample ) is drawn from each group.

On another note. you might be able to iteratively train your model by importing just parts of the data.

Comment: Can i do tjat before plotting the relationships?

Comment: Oh to just create a plot and see some relationships just plot the same amount of data for each class randomly sampled.

Comment: Thank you Duncan, It makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is so large that working with the entire thing is intractable then I'm not sure you have a choice other than sampling it (unless you're asking if a simple random sample, compared to other sampling techniques, is a good choice).

Another sampling technique specifically for imbalanced data is SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique).  The quick basic idea is that you take some number of Nearest Neighbors for an arbitrary member of your minority class and randomly 'create' new data points linearly between the pairs.  The paper describing this technique can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813.pdf

There's also a python implementation which can be found here:
https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html

The imbalanced-learn documentation has some pretty good illustrations/examples showing that SMOTE can pretty profoundly affect the decision boundary and is a good supplement to the paper even if you aren't planning on using it.

Comment: Should i use smote before plotting tje relationships?